# Error 0x01: The specified timestamp could not be found when signing a .msix package

Tags: package, signing, msix

I'm trying to sign my MSIX package via MSIX Hero app, but this error comes popping up even after changing the timestamp servers. Here is the error image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzsSJ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inKC7.png)

Comment: "[I downvoted because an image of your exception isn't helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/)"

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using the wrong timestep server. Try using another one, [Advanced Installer](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/digital-signature-timestamp.html) offer a list of predefined timestamp URLs.

How are you building the MSIX? If you want you can use the the free [Express edition from Advanced Installer](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/express) to generate and sign your package.

Or you can use this free command line tool to [automate signing for multiple MSIX packages](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/msix-tweaker-automating-digital-signing.html) - it is called MSIXTweaker.

*Disclaimer: I work on the team building Advanced Installer.*